# Map repeated columns in excel to xml or xsd

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I am trying to map excel columns to XML or XSD. I have a particular set of columns that are repeated. But in XML only the 1st set of repeated columns are mapped and rest of the repeated columns are ignored.

Suggestion are much appreciated